# c++ Why loops with more than 3 levels are skipped in c++

Tags: c++, loops

Just think about the following simple program example, why can't the part above 3 levels of nested loops be executed? Is there a better solution?

```
for(int i;i<a;i++){
  for(int j;j<b;j++){
    for(int k;k<c;k++){
       //The code here can be executed
      for(int z;z<d;z++){
         .....//The code here cannot be executed
      }
    }
  }
}
```

thank you very much.

Comment: thats a false premise, you can nest loops as deep as you like before you hit a limit. Please show a [mcve] of your code. We cannot explain you why, but we might be able to explain you what is acutally going on the code that made you come to that conclusion

Comment: `i`, `j`, `k`, `z` are not initialized, leading to UB.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop doesn't initialize the loop variable, so it's undefined what value it has, and thus the loop can be executed or not. It's undefined behavior.

```
for(int i; i < a; i++)
```

You should write something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
```

Or initialize it with something that satisfies your requirements.

The same applies to the other loops as well, of course.